# Fragment-Activity Communication with Event Bus

Tags: event-bus

I am trying to use `EventBus` to send text from my `tabLayout` to `Fragment` but for some unknown reason, the event is not been fired up. I get this error on my stack trace. I do not understand why the subscriber is not being registered.

```
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

**Fragment.java**

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
    @Subscribe
    public void receivedQueryMessage(BusMessage message){
        Log.d("MYLOG", "message");

    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getText() != null) {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(tab.getText());
                }
            }
```

**BusMessage.java**

```
public class BusMessage {
    private String message;

    public BusMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusMessage(tab.getText()));
```

Comment: it worked. however, the event only gets called after toggling the tab. I dont get the event on first launch. Any way around that?

Comment: it fire the event after toggling tab because you fire event in the TabSelectedListener  and of cause it don't event on first launch because you don't fire event on first launch (yours Captain Obvious)

Comment: okay. i moved that line of code to onCreate but got same result.

Comment: you subscribe to events in onStart() method so you should fire event after subscribing, something like this
        int currentTab = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusMessage(tabLayout.getTabAt(currentTab).getText()));